# Convert string into several integer arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

How do i break down this  " 01|15|59, 1|47|6, 01|17|20, 1|32|34, 2|3|1 " string into 5 integer arrays ?.

For example:

1. 01|15|59 becomes [01,15,59]
2. 1|47|6 becomes [1,47,6]

Comment: What did you try? - you just need two splits - and parseInt to not get octal numbers when there is a leading 0

Comment: I always wonder how people end up with such crazy data structures. Why don't you use something standard like JSON?

Comment: I always wonder how askers completely ignore the suggestions made right under the title of their question. As for the structures - that could easily be completely out of the hands of the asker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = string.trim().split(", ").map(el=>el.split("|").map(n=>+n))
```

this splits the string into an array of these groups ( yet as string )

```
  "1|2, 3|4" => ["1|2","3|4"]
```

then maps this array to a new array containing the strings splitted and converted to numbers:

```
=> [[1,2],[3,4]]
```

Comment: Thank you.I don't really understand what "map(n=>+n))" does though

Comment: @briin ["1","2"] => [1,2]